# Find the Second Point Of a 3D Line Segment Given Some Information

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given this information about a 3D line segment:

- XYZ of the first point
- Length of the line
- [Pitch and yaw angles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/perED.png)

How do I determine the XYZ of the second point?

I know how to do this with a 2D segment described by one angle:

- point2x = point1x + sin(angle) * length
- point2y = point1y + cos(angle) * length

But given a 3D segment described by two angles, I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pitch angle $p$ and yaw angle $y$ (in radians) and distance $r$, your displacement will be

$\mathbf{R} = \begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(p) & 0 & \sin(p) \\
  0 & 1 & 0 \\
  -\sin(p) & 0 & \cos(p)
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  \cos(y) & -\sin(y) & 0 \\
  \sin(y) & \cos(y) & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1
 \end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
  r  \\
  0 \\
  0
\end{bmatrix} 
$.

Then your new position from $\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
  x  \\
  y \\
  z\end{bmatrix} 
$ is $\mathbf{X+R}$.

Comment: I'm new to this stuff so to clarify, that's matrix multiplication being used to get R, and matrix addition for getting X?

Comment: **X** and **R** are column vectors, so the second part is vector addition.  In calculating **R**, multiplying a 3x3 matrix and a column vector gives another column vector.  Multiplying two 3x3 matrices gives another 3x3 matrix.

Comment: Ok, I'll have this part of my program implemented in a few days, if  your answer works I will accept. Ty beforehand!